# case in select statement?

Tags: php, sql, case

Is my statement correct

```
$uid=1;
$pby=1;

$db->query("SELECT 
  CASE WHEN (c.uid!='$uid' and c.uid!='$pby')
    THEN
      ( SELECT c.id, c.comment, c.uid,c.msgid, c.tstamp, u.fullname, u.img FROM 
   comments c join users u on c.uid=u.uid where c.msgid='$id' and 
   c.condition!='ga'   order by c.tstamp desc limit 10)
      )
 ELSE 
     ( SELECT c.id, c.comment, c.uid,c.msgid, c.tstamp, u.fullname, u.img FROM 
      comments c join users u on c.uid=u.uid where c.msgid='$id'  
      order by c.tstamp desc limit 10)
      )
  END
  FROM comments c where c.msg_id='$id'") ;
```

I tried this but throws empty result. dont know whats wrong

UPDATED TO

SELECT c.id, c.comment, c.uid,c.msgid, c.tstamp, u.fullname, u.img

```
  CASE WHEN (c.uid!='$uid' and c.uid!='$pby')
    THEN
      ( SELECT c.id, c.comment, c.uid,c.msgid, c.tstamp, u.fullname, u.img FROM 
   comments c join users u on c.uid=u.uid where c.msgid='$id' and 
   c.condition!='ga'   order by c.tstamp desc limit 10)
      )
 ELSE 
     ( SELECT c.id, c.comment, c.uid,c.msgid, c.tstamp, u.fullname, u.img FROM 
      comments c join users u on c.uid=u.uid where c.msgid='$id'  
      order by c.tstamp desc limit 10)
      )
  END
  FROM comments c join users u on c.uid=u.uid where c.msgid='$id'
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- still blank result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please specify the fields you want to select and update the query as

```
$db->query("SELECT field1, field2
  CASE WHEN (c.uid!='$uid' and c.uid!='$pby')
    THEN
      ( SELECT c.id, c.comment, c.uid,c.msgid, c.tstamp, u.fullname, u.img FROM 
   comments c join users u on c.uid=u.uid where c.msgid='$id' and 
   c.condition!='ga'   order by c.tstamp desc limit 10)
      )
 ELSE 
     ( SELECT c.id, c.comment, c.uid,c.msgid, c.tstamp, u.fullname, u.img FROM 
      comments c join users u on c.uid=u.uid where c.msgid='$id'  
      order by c.tstamp desc limit 10)
      )
  END
  FROM comments c where c.msg_id='$id'") ;
```

Comment: i want all these fields c.id, c.comment, c.uid,c.msgid, c.tstamp, u.fullname, u.img its a join . should i write it as join in main Select?

Comment: yah try it once..also you didn't have mentioned the database table for the alias 'u' in the query.

Comment: Please check the the updated code if it is right.. Updated code is not working

Comment: did you execute the query in phpmyadmin..is it showing any syntax error?

Comment: syntax error near 'CASE WHEN c.uid=1 THEN ( SELECT c.id, c.comment, c.uid,c.msgid,c.co' at line 3

Comment: does it return same syntx error with/without specifying fields.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40616/discussion-between-user2894116-and-jenz)